# Laravel 5.2 No supported encrypter found

Tags: php, laravel, exception

I have installed  a new laravel and fresh project on my server, I have configured with latest PHP, then I just clone the project from my server to localhost, then tried to change the configuration files and .env file to fix the below error, and it's not working, it's always shows an error like

```
"RuntimeException in compiled.php line 7706:
 No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid."
```

Any one have an idea to fix this issues,
FYI: My laravel version 5.2

Answer (score 2):

`php artisan key:generate`

If this does not automatically set your APP_KEY in your .env file, copy the key and paste it there

http://laravel.io/forum/06-09-2015-no-supported-encrypter-found-the-cipher-and-or-key-length-are-invalid

Comment: Ok i have a query, the .env file need to be configured, the connection database connection  string ?,.. Just for my reference

Comment: "No supported encrypter" means you haven't set your APP_KEY in your .env file. Run the above command to set it.

Comment: Have you got it to work yet? If yes, please select this as an answer so other people might benefit from it.

Comment: I have tried it seems the same issue, i think is there any issues with my server configuration?,, in my server php version is :PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 , so please let me know if i need to upgrade it to 5.6

Comment: If you run a `php artisan config:clear` after you've set a key?

Comment: i have tried using the above comment "php artisan config:clear" and generate a key using this comment "php artisan key:generate" after that the key is generated on server, i have placed that key to my .env file and app.php file then, i still the same issue